# Remove white spaces between words in a longtabu cell?

Tags: tables, longtabu, cell

I am trying to figure out why I have white spaces in some of my table cells between some words. This is how the problem looks like:
[image]

This is the code that I use:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont
\tabulinesep=1mm
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|l|X|X|X|l|l|}
\hline
  \textbf{Step No}
  & \textbf{Test Cases}
  & \textbf{Expected result}
  & \textbf{Actual result}
  & \textbf{Status}
\endhead \hline
1
& The user starts the mobile application and performs 5 minutes of \textbf{walking}.
& The system should recognise that the user is performing \gls{pa} and increments \textit{Active} time. 
& Works as expected e.g., updates the \gls{ui} by adding 5 minutes to the \gls{pa} progress bar in \textit{Today} \& \textit{History} screens.
& Pass
\\ \hline
2
& The user starts the mobile application and performs 5 minutes of \textbf{running}.
& The system should recognise that the user is performing \gls{pa} and increments \textit{Active} time. 
& Works as expected e.g., updates the \gls{ui} by adding 5 minutes to the 
\gls{pa} progress bar in \textit{Today} \& \textit{History} screens.
& Pass
\\ \hline
\end{longtabu}
\caption{Monitoring activity functional test snippet}
\label{tab:monitoring-com-ft}
\end{table}
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because the cell is using full justification.  If you add `\raggedright` to the cell, you will see a change.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Worked like a charm! Thank you very much! Could you please include your comment as an answer to my question so I can accept it. :)